# Removing list having empty list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
a = [[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4], [[], 2]]
```

and I want to remove the list that have inside an empty list.So the following result:

```
c = [[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4]]
```

I am using the following code:

```
c = []
for b in a:
    temp =[x for x in b if x]
    if len(temp)>1:
        c.append(temp)
```

It works ok, but it seems not to be a 'good way' of doing this task. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = [l for l in a if [] not in l]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
c = [x for x in a if [] not in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `list comprehension` and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function to check whether everything in the list evaluted to the `True`:

```
c = [i for i in a if all(i)]

print(c)
[[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function.

```
a = [[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4], [[], 2]]
assert filter(lambda o: [] not in o, a) == [[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4]]
```

Since in Python 3 filter is lazy, you may need explicit conversion to list.

```
assert list(filter(lambda o: [] not in o, a)) == [[['trial1', 'trial2'], 4]]
```